# What is the best library for image manipulation in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-manipulation

I'm working on an asp.net MVC web application and I need a library for image manipulation.
What is the best library for this case? I prefer to use an open source library.

Comment: What specific features are you looking for?

Comment: I need something as same as that you said. It seems similar to that I need.  I'm trying it thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ImageResizer.net. It has everything you need including code samples for SQL Server integration and croping with aspect ratio preserved:

http://imageresizing.net/

The most popular features are free and open-source:

- Resizing, cropping, rotating, flipping
- Borders, drop-shadows, padding, background colors
- Adjustable Jpeg compression. Multi-page tiff viewing
- Animated GIF frame selection. Comprehensive, real-time diagnostics
- Basic GIF and PNG encoding
- Gradient generation